# React Hooks : Carousel autoplay until a button is clicked, and don't finish the last remaining setTimeout()

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, react-hooks

I'm doing a kind of carousel in React.

```
function CareersReasonsCarousel(props) {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const [dir, setDir] = useState("next");
    const [auto, setAuto] = useState(true);

    const move = (pos) => {
        setAuto(false);
        setCurrent(current+pos);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (auto) {
                setCurrent(current+1);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }, [current]);
}
```

And lower, in my `return`, I have

```
<div className="arrow next" onClick={ () => { move(1) }}><img src={ arrow_right } alt="" /></div>
```

I want the carousel to start on autoplay when the page is first loaded, and lose autoplay when someone clicks the "next" or "previous" arrows. Problem is, the way it's set up, when I click the arrows, the carousel will still wait for the rest of the 5 seconds delay and execute the last "setTimeout" it has registered, and only then will it see that `auto` is `false` and it doesn't have to automate anymore.

How can I get it to verify the value of `auto`, not when the setTimeout is registered, but when it's supposed to be executed (after the 5 seconds delay) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your `useEffect` dependency array so it references the current value of `auto` rather than the one from the previous render. You also need to call `clearTimeout` if necessary on the previous timer when the effect is re-run, and it's usually a good idea to return a clean-up function if your component gets un-mounted to avoid memory leaks.

```
const timerRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if(timerRef.current){
        clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    }
    timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        if (auto) {
            setCurrent(c=>c+1);
        }
    }, 5000);
    return ()=>clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
}, [auto, current]);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still does the same. Let's say I see the slide switch, and then click "next" after exactly 2 seconds, it'll automatically switch one last time 3 seconds later, and only then register that `auto === false`. The issue seems to be with the setTimeout(), there must be something about scoping I don't understand.

Comment: Wow, it worked ! I'll be honest I don't really get how useRef() works, but I'll find more tutorials on it ! I was about to use a timer that incremented every 100 ms and verified `auto` every time. I'm glad I don't have to rely on such a clumsy solution. Thanks so much !

Comment: no probs... useRef is just a mutable object that you can use to hold on to stuff between renders - you access the reference relevant to the current render with `.current` - in this case, the ref to the timer. By using it here we can cancel the old timer and create a fresh one when the effect runs. Without it, the ref to the original timeout is lost on subsequent renders, so it it can't be cleared.

Comment: p.s. this is a long but excellent explanation of what's going on: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/